# Cross-domain users in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

We are using Dynamics CRM 2015 on-premise. And we are trying to make off-site users be able to use the system. We know that we can enable IFD (Internet Facing Deployment) for them to login. But the problem is that they are working mostly in Outlook with a different domain. They need to track emails from that inbox.

For example, the CRM system is set up at example.com. And off-site users are working with their inboxes name@test.com. They want to use the CRM system and track their emails in test.com inbox.

I doubt that it is possible to do that, but any thought or advise is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I guess it is impossible to do that. The users have to be in AD. For your reference: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/163766

Comment: Is it possible to make an AD trust between the domains? In that case the users will show up in the AD of the CRM system and you can add them to the CRM.

Comment: I am investigating on enabling claims-based authentication and IFD using ADFS so that we can set up trusted account for partner to login. Please refer this link: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn554245.aspx

Comment: I don't know how you get the users into your CRM when you are using two ADFS servers to handle the federation of users between ADs. It might be so "easy" that as soon as you get the federation up and running you just enter domain2\username and it's working